# iOS - Mimic blur-and-enlarge effect before peeking

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, 3dtouch

I'm looking to use 3D touch to perform an action when the user force presses a `UITableViewCell` and I want to mimic the blur effect of peek and pop to signal to the user that the force press option is available.  However, the peek and pop API is not very intuitive and doesn't allow me to cancel the pop, so I was wondering if there's any way to mimic the blur-and-enlarge effect that iOS provides before the view is peeked.

I also notice that in [the documentation for CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410827-backgroundfilters) it says that the `backgroundFilters` property is not supported at all on iOS, which is how most posts advise that I implement a Gaussian blur such as the one iOS uses for peeking.

Is it at all practical to emulate that effect? Thank you.